# Mismatched anonymous define() module IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, requirejs

I've got a bug with requireJS and ie8 :

```
Mismatched anonymous define() module
```

This error appears only in IE8.

**I know the origin :**

I'm usign es5shim and json3 library added by an HTML comment like that :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

In fact it seems that es5shim and json3 use a define() function. This is the origin of the error.

I can solve it removing the HTML comment and loading these librairies like other in requirejs.

But i wan't these librairies only for IE8 !

I don't know what to do !!

Thx guys

Comment: Are you saying that this error is only given by IE8 and other browsers are fine?

Comment: Also, have you looked at this: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html

Comment: Only in IE8 i've read the docs ... it seems come from es5shim and json3 library added through an IE hack in html ... I hate IE ...

Comment: I think you'll have to show some code to be able to take your problem resolution further. Would you be able to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: And oh, I hate IE, too. At least <IE8. IE9 is pretty decent.

Comment: Which versions of es5shim and json3? Are you loading those scripts as `<script>` tags or through requirejs shims?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. In fact es5shim and json3 use the define() function for AMD compatibility.

But i have to load them out of requirejs via an HTML comment :

```
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
```

The matter was i add this comment after the `data-main` :

```
  <!-- build:js scripts/amd-app.js -->
  <script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/scripts/main" </script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

So it fails. If i put the comment before the `data-main` it works :

```
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

 <!-- build:js scripts/amd-app.js -->
 <script src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/scripts/main" </script>
 <!-- endbuild -->
```